# How to sum up/aggregate values on Firebase

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have just added few values using Firebase:
[Screen from Firebase](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zY0p9.png)

I would like to sum up those values and display 15 as a result in the log.

Here is my code:

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        DatabaseReference beersRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Rank");

        final ArrayList<Integer> score = new ArrayList<>();

        score.add(9);
        score.add(2);
        score.add(4);

        beersRef.push().setValue(score);


        beersRef.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {


            }

            @Override
            public void onChildChanged(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onChildRemoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onChildMoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });
```

Answer (score 1):

To achieve this, please use the following code. It's the simples way.

```
DatabaseReference rootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
DatabaseReference rankRef = rootRef.child("Rank");
ValueEventListener eventListener = new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        int sum = 0;
        for(DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
            int value = ds.getValue(Integer.class);
            sum =+ sum + value;
        }
        Log.d("TAG", sum);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {}
};
rankRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(eventListener);
```

Your output will be: `15`

Answer (score -1):

use ValueEventListner and , don't use childEventListner,
follow the below line...Here " UI and UI.class " means...java class name ..where you put getters and setters ...
here I store int value in firebase...so need to convert int value to String and set a text to text viewholder...if u don't store in int ..than u can use String

```
beersRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {`
                    @Override
                    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {``

                        int total = 0;   

                        for (DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {

                            UI result = ds.getValue(UI.class);
                            total = total + result.getMrp_final();

                        }

                        String tl = total + "";
                        tv_total.setText(tl);

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

                    }
                });
```

make sure int total value is zero...
thankyou